# Unlimited Custom Fields on Google Contacts

Tags: database

"I'm new to DB design and was wondering about how google created their contacts to allow unlimited Phone numbers, addresses, custom fields, etc. Can you give an example of how the DB tables will look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [Entity-Attribute-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) or a no-relational database like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) or [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I would make a Table "Fields" with the following Rows:

Fields:

- FieldID
- ContactID
- Name
- Value

To add an E-Mail address to Contact "Henry" with ID 7:

FieldID : Next highest ID

ContactID : 7

Name : EMail

Value : test@hisdomain.com